# Why does border radius affect box shadow?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Please consider the following CSS:

```
div {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
}

div > div {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
}

div > div:hover {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,255,.2)
}
```

with the following HAML:

```
%div
  %div
```

Hovering on the inner element causes the border radius to change, as well as  the background color. However, it also affects the box shadow. This should not happen. Please see snippet below:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yGvydK?editors=1100

How can this be explained? Is this a bug in Google Chrome? It doesn't appear to be happening in Firefox, IE or Edge. I run Chrome version 71.0.3578.98 on a 64 bit Windows 10 laptop.

**EDIT**

Behavior in Chrome (incorrect):

[image: Non-hovered state]
[image: Hovered state. Note how the shadow suddenly looks different on the left, top, and right.]

Note how the shadow suddenly looks different on the left, top, and right when hovering.

**EDIT 2**

Behavior in Firefox 64.0 (correct):

[image: Non-hovered state]
[image: Hovered state]

Comment: Same result on Firefox and Edge, and of course it does...you change the border radius on hover so how can it not ?? The shadow is based on the element its set and will render the same shape.

Comment: Are you running the same version of Chrome as I am? Because if not, you can't claim the behavior is equal on all browsers. Please don't downvote my question just because you can't reproduce the issue. Also, did you even read the question properly? I state that the **box shadow** is unwantedly changed, not the border radius.

Comment: Do you think I would say _same result_ if I weren't sure ? ... that attitude is a wrong one, and if you read my first comment again, you'll see I said _the shadow is based on the element shape_. Furthermore, this is well showed/explained in the docs, e.g. MDN, so go there and read. If you want round border and square shadow, use a pseudo for the shadow

Comment: I understand that a change in shape would affect the box shadow, but it wouldn't explain the effect shown above. I also attached screenshots for Firefox, please compare those.

Comment: I am saying it again, I don't get that result using the two browser versions you mention, they render the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this was a bug in Chrome 71. Updating to Chrome 72 resolved the issue.